# How do I prevent my chart from rerendering? (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, rerender, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs-2

So everytime I use setState my component rerenders. But I don't want my chart to rerender. My question is how do I prevent my chart from rerendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new component for the chart. Prevent the rerender by memoizing it with Higher Order Component `memo`.

Answer (score 0):

Though the issue is not very clear, but You can use useRef which does not
Re-renders the UI.